# How to avoid \ in json response in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

When I run these code

```
Return response ()->json($data,200);
```

Output

```
[{\"Gender\":\"male\"}]
```

But I want output without \

```
 [{"gender":"male"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option.

`json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

The output you're seeing is valid json, as `\` and `\/` are equivalent in JSON. Forward slashes can cause problems when preceded by `<`

Comment: I already used used JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES  still getting \ in json output , any other suggestions please

Comment: Are you parsing the response on the client? `JSON.parse(response)`